# Combined GET and POST requests HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am looking for some **advise** about the following, I have a **HttpUtil class** (util) in which I have my sendGetRequest- and sendPostRequest methods. 
I use them to perform a **successfull** login to a website from which I am going to fetch some data.
Now, I call these methods in my **MainActivity** in a Asynctask:

> ```
> protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
>     try {
>             //1. GET request 
>               util.sendGetRequest(loginURL, null);
>             //2. Post request 
>               util.sendPostRequest(loginURL, null);
>             //3. Final GET request 
>               util.sendGetRequest(resultURL, null);
>             // Read stream
>                String[] response = util.readMultipleLinesRespone();
>                   for (String line : response) {
>                System.out.println(line);
>                }
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             return false;
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         }
> ```

I am looking for a solution so that one **waits** for another to finish (1st get then post, finally get), if it`s possible I want to keep this util.class intact and not put everything in the Asynctask (doInBackground).
Is this possible or do I have the wrong approach?

Your opinions and advise please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I normally use is this:

- First, consider using an Event for instance a library like [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) that will not only decouple your code but also make it so easy to notify your activity when the first HttpGet request is completed.
- Next, start your GET request inside **doInBackground** and then notify your activity once the process is completed - normally inside **onPostExecute**
- When in your activity, assuming you use the EventBus library, you can execute the next AsyncTask which will do your next task like doing a POST request accordingly.

Using this approach should really make your life easier - specifically helps you know when something is completed and so you can proceed with the next task as needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx Eenvincible, "event" is the keyword indeed, nice library. Thx for the info.

Comment: I am glad you found it helpful Simon!

Comment: You can take this a notch up by showing a progress dialog whenever an operation is ongoing like inside onPreExecute() and dismiss it onPostExecute - helps users know that something is happening and should wait

Comment: That was my intention anyhow, already got a progress dialog in place :)

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can have two AsyncTasks. One for get and other for post. First execute get request. Then in onPostExecute of the first AsyncTask execute the second AsyncTask that sends the post request in doInBackground();

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpUtil class should somehow signal that the response is received. 
For example, put this code in HttpUtil to signal end of operation:

```
synchronized (this) {
   done = true;
   notifyAll();
}
```

and this code will wait for the operation to end:

```
while(!util.isDone()) {
  try {
    synchronized(util) { util.wait(); }

  } catch(Exception e) { ... }
}
```